# How to suppress warning "extension 'X' overrides commands: Y"?

Tags: mercurial

I have added an extension  `evolve =` into `.hgrc` and it throws

> `extension 'evolve' overrides commands: uncommit`

I also commented `; uncommit =` extension  but when I do that cmder gets confused by that error because it shows `C:\dev\WebApp 'evolve'` instead of `C:\dev\WebApp (dev)`

How to fix/suppress this evolve-related warning (or error) in mercurial?